# Select from one table based on another tables values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a question if it's possible to select from one table based on another tables values in the same query. In my case I have two tables named `follow` and `score`.

Follow

```
------------------------
| follower | following |
------------------------
| Uname2   | Uname1    |
------------------------
```

Score

```
--------------------
| username | score |
--------------------
| Uname1   |   1   |
--------------------
| Uname1   |   2   |
--------------------
```

What i'm tryin to accomplice is to first get who the user is following and then get that users total score. I have tried with inner join etc but can't get it to work.

Query

```
"SELECT follow.following, score.SUM('score') FROM follow INNER JOIN score ON follow.following=score.username WHERE follow.follower='Uname2'";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get one record use this:

```
SELECT
  f.following,
  SUM(s.score) as score
FROM
  Follow f, Score s
WHERE
  f.following = s.username
  AND f.follower = 'Uname2'
```

To get the sum for each try:

```
SELECT
  f.follower,
  f.following,
  SUM(s.score) as score
FROM
  Follow f, Score s
WHERE
  f.following = s.username
GROUP BY f.follower
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e655d3/9) example.

Comment: Thanks I can now get one users result! How can I change the query so that it prints out every user and score that is followed by a specific user?

Comment: Maybe something like `SELECT s.username, f.follower, SUM(s.score) as score FROM Follow f, Score s WHERE f.following = s.username GROUP BY s.username`?. Here's the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e655d3/14) example.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to include a `GROUP BY` clause here, at the end of your query add `GROUP BY follow.following`.

Answer (score 0):

Use **GROUP BY** like this. Hope it will help.

```
SELECT follow.following, score.SUM('score') FROM follow INNER JOIN score ON follow.following=score.username WHERE follow.follower='Uname2' GROUP BY follow.following
```

Comment: I have tried with group by but that doesnt work either.

Comment: Try this. Select a.following, sum(b.score) from follow a inner join on score b where b.username=a.following group by a.following